# How to group test cases using regular expression of ng e2e with protractor jasmins3

Tags: protractor, jasmine, smoke-testing

I am using `ng e2e --protractorConfig=e2e/protractor.conf.js` to run my e2e test.

I want to add a regular expression like @smoke to this command. But when I add `--grep='@smoke'` to it as:

```
ng e2e --protractorConfig=e2e/protractor.conf.js --grep='@smoke'
```

I get errors.

What is the correct way to group test cases?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You may group tests as suites like below:

Conf.js

```
suites: { 
        smoke: 'tests/e2e/smoke/*.js', 
        performance: 'tests/e2e/performance/*.js',
      regression: 'tests/e2e/regression/*.js'
 },
```

And run like below:

```
 $ protractor conf.js --suite smoke
```

#### Using jasmine framework, tests can also be organized/grouped using a regular expression.

You can add something like @smoke, @regressions to your tests and then only run those ones by passing the grep flag.

```
it('should do stuff @smoke', function() { ... });
```

Then run protractor passing the grep flag:

```
protractor conf.js --grep='@smoke'
```

Comment: when i am using this protractor conf.js --grep='@smoke' Still i am getting error conf.js
exports.config={ seleniumAddress:"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", specs:['@smoke'],
};
directConnect=true Is there anything , that i am missing?